# Using Node in Map, C++

Tags: c++, class, nodes, public, std-pair

```
class MtmMap {   
    public:    
    class Pair {     
         public:   
         Pair(const KeyType& key, const ValueType& value) :     
             first(key),       
             second(value) { }    
         const KeyType first;    
         ValueType second;    
     };     
    class node {    
        friend class MtmMap;    
        Pair data;    
        node* next;     
        public:    
        node();    
        node(const Pair& pair){
            data.Pair(pair.first , pair.second);
            next = NULL;
        }    
    };
    node* temp = new node(pair);
}
```

errors:

> no matching function for call to 'mtm::MtmMap<int, int, AbsCompare>::Pair::Pair()'
>   invalid use of 'mtm::MtmMap<int, int>::Pair::Pair'
>   required from 'void mtm::MtmMap::insert(const
>   mtm::MtmMap<KeyType, ValueType, CompareFunction>::Pair&) [with KeyType = int;  ValueType = int;
>   CompareFunction = AbsCompare]'

Comment: You're clearly not showing us all of your code. MtmMap is presumably a template, yes? But you're not showing us the template. Also, it helps to indicate which line the error occurs on.

Answer (score 0):

By defining a constructor for `Pair` which takes arguments you remove the implicit default constructor that takes no arguments. When you have a member of type `Pair` in `node` it therefore has to have arguments passed to it in the initialiser list of node, you need to replace your node constructor with this:

```
    node(const Pair& pair) : data(pair.first, pair.second) {
        next = NULL;
    }
```

Which will call the constructor on `data` properly. [Learn Cpp](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/101-constructor-initialization-lists/) has a tutorial on how initialiser lists work which you may want to read.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing that jumps out at me is this line:

```
node* temp = new node(pair);
```

It looks like you're trying to `new` a class within a class definition.  That could be part of the problem.  Also, this area looks a little confused:

```
node(const Pair& pair){
  data.Pair(pair.first , pair.second);
  next = NULL;
}
```

It looks like you're trying to call the `Pair` constructor directly.  I'm not sure if that's valid C++ or not.  Really, just define a copy-constructor for `Pair` like so:

```
Pair( Pair const& other )
  : first( other.first )
  , second( other.second )
{}
```

Then, that block becomes

```
node( Pair const& pair )
  : data( pair )
  , next( NULL )
{}
```

You might also check into `std::pair`.